# Image rotation using jquery/css

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I need to implement the image rotation. I have an iframe to load my image. 
I have the image inside the iframe.

I use css (transform) to rotate. The image is rotated but the div is not resized.

```html
 

<div id="object_box" style="width: 1100px; height: 681px;" >
    <iframe id="objframe" style="width: 1100px; height: 681px; background: transparent;" scrolling="no" src="objectload.xhtml?fid=4423"></iframe>
</div>
```

```
function rotateImg(){

    angle = (angle+90)%360;
    $("#im_temp_load").attr("class","rotate"+angle);

    var imgWidth = "";
    var imgHeight = "";

    if(angle=="90" || angle=="270"){

        imgWidth = $("#im_temp_load").height();
        imgHeight = $("#im_temp_load").width();
    }else{

        imgWidth = $("#im_temp_load").width();
        imgHeight = $("#im_temp_load").height();

    }


    $("#object_box").css({"width": imgWidth, "height": imgHeight});
    $("#objframe").css({"width": imgWidth, "height": imgHeight});

}
```

Comment: Why use jQuery when CSS is much more suited to this task?

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you really need to use jQuery (CSS transforms wouldn't work)? Have you tried existing plugins ( https://www.google.com/search?output=search&q=jquery%20rotate )? What do you mean by "implement an icon"?

Comment: I need to resize the container also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I found the issue. We can access the parent div by window.parent.document

```
function rotateImgLeft(){

    angle = (angle+90)%360;
    $("#im_temp_load").attr("class","rotate"+angle);

    var imgWidth = "";
    var imgHeight = "";

    if(angle=="90" || angle=="270"){

        imgWidth = $("#im_temp_load").height();
        imgHeight = $("#im_temp_load").width();
    }else{

        imgWidth = $("#im_temp_load").width();
        imgHeight = $("#im_temp_load").height();

    }

    $('#object_box', window.parent.document).css({"width": imgWidth, "height": imgHeight});
    $('#objframe', window.parent.document).css({"width": imgWidth, "height": imgHeight});

}


function rotateImgRight(){

    angle = (angle+270)%360;
    $("#im_temp_load").attr("class","rotate"+angle);

    var imgWidth = "";
    var imgHeight = "";

    if(angle=="90" || angle=="270"){

        imgWidth = $("#im_temp_load").height();
        imgHeight = $("#im_temp_load").width();
    }else{

        imgWidth = $("#im_temp_load").width();
        imgHeight = $("#im_temp_load").height();

    }

    $('#object_box', window.parent.document).css({"width": imgWidth, "height": imgHeight});
    $('#objframe', window.parent.document).css({"width": imgWidth, "height": imgHeight});

}
```